# Input and Output Variable Array Using Method in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2 class, Testing and Main. Class testing have 2 attribute a and b. I want to make the program work with array and the value input by user.

```
public class Testing{
private String a,b;
public Testing(a,b){
    this.a=a;
    this.b=b;
 }  
public void getA(){
    return a;
 }
public void getB(){
    return b;
 }
}
```

And the next is my main class

```
public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int x,i;
System.out.print("How many lines? ");
x = s.nextInt();
//method inputData
Testing ts[] = new Testing[x];
for (i=0; i<x; i++)
    System.out.print("Enter Value A :"); String a = ss.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter Value B "); String b = s.nextInt();
    ts[i] = new Testing(a,b);
 }
//method outputData
System.out.println("Output---");
for(i=0; i<x; i++){
    System.out.print("Value A"+i+" "+ts[i].getA());
    System.out.print("Value B"+i+" "+ts[i].getB());
 }
}
```

It's actually work fine, but I want to move code bellow //methode inputData and //method outputData from Main to Testing. So, I just call methods `inputData()` and `outputData()` from Main. But I don't how to do it. 
I'd be thankful if you help me.

Answer (score 1):

First, the methods should be declared outside of the main method. Just copy the method's section to the testing file. Then, you instanciate an object of testing:

```
Testing test = new Testing(...)
test.inputData()
test.outputData()
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't understand, why you're doing this but you can try like this;

1.

Testing.java;

```
public class Testing {
    private String a, b;

    public Testing(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public static int outputData(int x, Testing[] ts) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            System.out.print("Value A" + i + " " + ts[i].getA());
            System.out.print("Value B" + i + " " + ts[i].getB());
        }
        return i;
    }

    public static Testing[] inputData(Scanner ss, Scanner s, int x) {
        int i;
        Testing ts[] = new Testing[x];
        for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter Value A :");
            String a = ss.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Value B ");
            String b = s.nextLine();
            ts[i] = new Testing(a, b);
        }
        return ts;
    }
}
```

and Main.java;

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x, i;
        System.out.print("How many lines? ");
        x = s.nextInt();
//method inputData
        Testing[] ts = Testing.inputData(ss, s, x);
//method outputData
        System.out.println("Output---");
        i = Testing.outputData(x, ts);
    }

}
```

2.

Also as @Fabiotk said, you can do `inputData` and `outputData` methods `non-static` and use with creating class object.

Testing.java;

```
public class Testing {
    private String a, b;

    public Testing(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public int outputData(int x, Testing[] ts) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            System.out.print("Value A" + i + " " + ts[i].getA());
            System.out.print("Value B" + i + " " + ts[i].getB());
        }
        return i;
    }

    public Testing[] inputData(Scanner ss, Scanner s, int x) {
        int i;
        Testing ts[] = new Testing[x];
        for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter Value A :");
            String a = ss.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Value B ");
            String b = s.nextLine();
            ts[i] = new Testing(a, b);
        }
        return ts;
    }
}
```

And Main.java;

```
  public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Testing test = new Testing("a", "b");

        int x, i;
        System.out.print("How many lines? ");
        x = s.nextInt();
        //method inputData
        Testing[] ts = test.inputData(ss, s, x);
        //method outputData
        System.out.println("Output---");
        test.outputData(x, ts);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do some thing like this ,but these methods should create out of main method :
To call these methods you should like this in your main method:

```
  Testing  ts = new Testing();
    ts.inputData(4);
    ts.outputData(3);
```

For creating methods do this:

```
  //method inputData
  Testing ts[] = new Testing[x];
   for (i=0; i<x; i++)
  System.out.print("Enter Value A :"); String a = ss.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Enter Value B "); String b = s.nextInt();
   ts[i] = new Testing(a,b);
}
```

Method inputData become:

```
 public int[] inputData(int x){
    Testing ts[] = new Testing[x];
     for (i=0; i<x; i++)
     System.out.print("Enter Value A :"); String a = ss.nextLine();
     System.out.print("Enter Value B "); String b = s.nextInt();
   ts[i] = new Testing(a,b);
   return ts;
   }
```

This:

```
 System.out.println("Output---");
for(i=0; i<x; i++){
System.out.print("Value A"+i+" "+ts[i].getA());
System.out.print("Value B"+i+" "+ts[i].getB());
}
```

Become method outputData:

```
 public void outputData(int x){
  for(i=0; i<x; i++){
   System.out.print("Value A"+i+" "+ts[i].getA());
    System.out.print("Value B"+i+" "+ts[i].getB());
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You have an array of Testing-instances. It would have to be something like a static print-method in the Testing class which would accept an array of Testing-instances. You could do that but it would be a wrong separation of concerns.
Same thing goes for the input-method.

You could write a print-method in Testing which would output the value of a and b *for that specific instance of Testing* and then in your main method call that print method.

Maybe something like:

```
public class Testing {
// ...

    public void getDataFromUser(Scanner s) {
         System.out.print("Enter Value A :"); this.a = s.nextLine();
         System.out.print("Enter Value B "); this.b = s.nextInt();
    }

    public void printToSysout() {
         System.out.print("Value A"+i+" "+getA());
         System.out.print("Value B"+i+" "+getB());
    }
}
```

And then you'd keep the loop in your main method like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    // ..get x and such
    for (i=0; i<x; i++) {
        ts[i] = new Testing(); // create a no-args constructor for Testing
        ts[i].getDataFromUser(s);
    }

    System.out.println("Output---");
    for(i=0; i<x; i++) {
        ts[i].printToSysout();
    }
}
```

Also, 'Testing' is a really bad classname. Classnames are typically nouns and descriptive of what they contain. Maybe TestData or something?